# Firefox is not responding when I close all active Firefox windows and reopen

Tags: windows, firefox

My Firefox browser does not open when I close all the its windows and reopen again.
A message shows up similar to :

> To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.

The error says that Firefox is already running but is not responding.
How do I open a new instance of Firefox?

Comment: which operating system you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's Windows do the following

1. Open Task manager of Windows. Navigate to process tab.
2. Choose process `firefox.exe`.
3. Right Click on End process tree.
4. Now start Firefox.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a linux system run the following on a console:

`sudo killall firefox`

Answer (score 2):

For closing **Firefox.exe** application through Powershell use:

```
Stop-Process -Name firefox -Force
```

and for Command-Line use:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM firefox.exe /T
```

To quickly access the Command-Line or Powershell use `WIN-button + R`on your Keyboard. There you can type `powershell` to open the Powershell or `cmd` to open the Command-Line. You can even directly type commands of the Command-Line in there.

*Note: Writing is not casesensitive. In Powershell you can even leave the extension for .exe files.*